# Undeleting file in Cornerstone

Tags: svn, delete-file, revisions, cornerstone

So, I did what seems to be a big mistake. I accidentally deleted a very important file in Cornerstone from my Repository and can't get it back.

I have clicked at Revert 20-30 times now but it seems that it won't revert changes since the first change I did today (which was when the file was deleted). How can I go back to earlier revisions?

I really appreciate help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Revert" only reverts local changes that are not yet checked in. If you want to roll back to a previous revision, use [`svn update -r1234`](http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.0/re28.html) with the revision number you want to go back to.